# Spaces in folder names suddenly causing IIS problems

Tags: asp.net, iis

**Issue**

```
<a href='/assets/Roses%20are%20red/Violet%20are%20blue/I_love_you.pdf'>I Love You</a>
```

mapped to (as a virtual directory in the website called assets):

```
D:\Digital Assets\Roses are red\Violets are blue\I_love_you.pdf
```

Does not work with the combination of IIS v6 and .NET 4.0.

**Background**

It does work with the combination of IIS v6 and .NET 2.0. Our testing also shows it does work with IIS v7 and .NET 4.0. However, our servers are currently running Server 2003, so we have limitations on what upgrades we can make.

We're running IIS version 6 on Server 2003 with .NET 4.0. In our database we have a list of helpful relative links pointing to PDF documents. Some of the folders containing these PDF documents have spaces in their names, e.g., "/Roses are red/Violet are blue/I_love_you.pdf". When it is rendered on a page we're ending up with I love you.pdf.

I have code in Global.asax that quickly verifies that a PDF actually exists, if not it throws a 404 right away. This code is functioning correctly, and verifies that the files do exist.

Unfortunately, these links are performing several cycles looking for the file (that does physically exist) and then throwing up a 404 or 502.

For testing, we removed the spaces from the folder name on the server, and tried the link directly without the %20's. The PDF document opened right up without any delay.

This just started happening with the recent .NET upgrade on the server. Is there any way to turn this behavior off?

**Global.asax**

```
Private ReadOnly _assetTails As New List(Of String) _
    (".pdf|.htm|.doc|.xls|.jpg|.ppt|.zip|.exe|.wmv|.msi|.tif|.swf|.mov|.mp4|.flv".Split("|"c).ToList())

Sub Application_BeginRequest(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs)
    Dim tail = IO.Path.GetExtension(Request.Url.Segments.ToList().Last()).ToLower()

....

    If _assetTails.Exists(Function(x)
                              Return tail.StartsWith(x)
                          End Function) Then
        Dim fullOrigionalPath As String = HttpContext.Current.Request.Url.ToString()
        Dim filename = Server.MapPath(Server.UrlDecode(Request.Url.AbsolutePath))
        If Not WebUtility.FileExists(fullOrigionalPath, filename) Then
            Dim sError = String.Format("File '{0}' not found", filename)
            Throw New HttpException(404, sError)
        End If
    End If
```

**WebUtil.FileExists**

```
Public Shared Function FileExists(ByVal urlOriginal As String, ByVal filename As String) As Boolean
    Dim logger As Logger = LogManager.GetCurrentClassLogger
    Try
        logger.Debug(String.Format("Does file '{1}' exist for '{0}'?", urlOriginal, filename))
        If File.Exists(filename) Then
            Return True
        Else
            Dim sError = String.Format("File '{0}' not found", filename)
            logger.Error(sError)
            Return False
        End If
    Catch ex As Exception
        logger.Error(ex.Message)
        Return False
    End Try
End Function
```

Comment: Your post is confusing. It might help if you said exactly what you're doing and when. Including the code from your `global.asax` may be helpful too.

Comment: You say the links are "performing several cycles looking for the file." What do you mean by that? And, is it returning a straight 404, or a 404.* (e.g. 404.11)? In what cases do you see a 502? Have you tried adding code after your existence check to verify that you can also read the file? Lastly, have you considered serving up the files' content directly rather than relying on IIS' static content handling?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If requests for static files like coming through the ASP.NET pipeline on an IIS 6.0 instance, then someone has probably setup a wildcard application mapping. I'd recommend bypassing the ASP.NET pipeline entirely for your static content. That should free you from any behavioral differences between .NET versions. It will require configuration of your web server.

[Installing Wildcard Application Mappings (IIS 6.0)](http://www.google.com/search?q=%22Installing%20Wildcard%20Application%20Mappings%20%28IIS%206.0%29%22&btnI&site:microsoft.com)

First, you'll need to find your application's "identifier" by looking in IIS Manager:

[image]

*Note that this image is from a [related post on Steven Sanderson's blog](http://blog.stevensanderson.com/2008/07/07/overriding-iis6-wildcard-maps-on-individual-directories/).*

To remove the wildcard map on particular directory, open a command prompt, switch to %SystemDrive%\inetpub\AdminScripts c:\Inetpub\AdminScripts, and run:

```
adsutil.vbs SET /W3SVC/[identifer]/root/Content/ScriptMaps ""
```

replacing [identifier] with the "identifier" number of your application. Also, you could replace "Content" with the path to any other directory. Now, your /Content folder will now bypass the wildcard mapping, and its files will be served natively by IIS.

If you can't do this for the entire application, you could setup a virtual directory for your content and turn off the wildcard mapping for just that directory.

Another alternative would be intercept the requests for those files yourself and stream back their contents directly rather than relying on the ASP.NET pipeline's default behavior.

Comment: We had one twist to this though. We set up the Virtual Folder that contained the informational content (mostly PDFs) to an application, then we turned off the wildcard mapping for that app folder. We also put the app folder in an app pool for IIS6 and .NET 2.0.